# Prevent Debian from auto-enabling systemd services at package post-install

Tags: debian, systemd

On Debian, if the package you're installing has systemd services, they will be automatically enabled and started at post-install. I have found [a way to disable the latter](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2013/10/06/policy-rc-d-do-not-start-services-automatically/), but not the former (yet).

It seems like the post-install scripts use `deb-systemd-helper` to do this, which means disabling it shouldn't be impossible.

[image]

**Edit:** This is what I ended up doing.

`/etc/systemd/system-preset/00-disable-all.preset`:

```
disable *
```

Comment: I believe presets would be the way to go here...

Comment: How can I use presets to prevent all package installations from enabling their services though?

Comment: Look through the duplicate question's answer regarding presets and to the systemd doc which shows how to default-deny services.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like "you can just create a symlink to mask `ssh.service`, before installing the package".  E.g. `ln -s /dev/null /etc/systemd/system/ssh.service`.

I suppose this requires that you know the name of all services created by the package.

I am aware of one minor disadvantage for this approach.  If you have a masked service which is also marked as "enabled", then `systemd` will log a warning during startup.

Note that a `systemd` "mask" will prevent the service from being started by any method, including manually running `systemctl start ssh`.  So depending on what you want to do, you might want to remove the mask after you've installed the package.

---

If the package is `ssh`, it has a specific hack you can use instead! Bad news: this implies that a specific hack is needed in the package because all the other approaches have disadvantages. But you can have a look at the approaches I considered if you like :-). [Configuring my sshd securely (with automation)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321621/configuring-my-sshd-securely-with-automation)

Comment: I'm looking for a way that works for every package that does this, and the masking one is one of the solutions that I'd like to avoid.

Comment: @Hwi417 I think you might have to resort to a `dpkg-divert` hack. I really want a feature similar to this, but I couldn't find it either.

Comment: There is always the possibility of avoiding systemd altogether ;)

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro and doing what, exactly? I think so far I've assumed systemd for simplicity, but I don't see how avoiding it helps.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro seems this question has been closed because it apparently has an answer on another question which uses systemd-specific features :-P.

Comment: @sourcejedi I have seen it, it seems appropriate. I use Debian Stretch without any traces of systemd at all. (Devuan does not qualify)

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro perhaps I am being too cryptic. I mean to ask, if you avoid systemd and instead use sysvinit (or however you prefer to manage your system!), how do you override the Debian default policy of both starting *and enabling* services when a package is installed?  I've just learnt how to do so under systemd - but I don't know how to do so if I avoid systemd!

Comment: @StephenKitt it must indeed be lacking documentation, because from all the documentation I've read my understanding was that `policy-rc.d` only applies to *starting* services, and did not affect the automatic *enabling* of services.  As in the text of this question, for example.

Comment: @sourcejedi It just hit me now you want to prevent enabling and not starting. hmmmm Dummy me.