# Does Debian actually have a written policy to start services on installation?

Tags: debian, services

Debian packages usually start services right after installing them. This is a well-known phenomenon, given [tens](https://cowboyprogrammer.org/2016/10/dont-start-service-on-install-of-debian-package/) [of](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/484092/prevent-debian-from-auto-enabling-systemd-services-at-package-post-install) [webpages](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2013/10/06/policy-rc-d-do-not-start-services-automatically/) [explaining](https://serverfault.com/questions/567474/how-can-i-install-packages-without-starting-their-associated-services) [how](https://weicode.wordpress.com/2016/02/19/install-debian-package-without-automatically-starting-daemons/) to disable this behavior. As far as I remember, this has been in place before `systemd` has been adopted.

My question is, is it an official policy? Has this rule been written down anywhere? I've tried looking for it in the [Debian Policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/index.html), but couldn't find relevant notes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is addressed in [the “Managing the links” section of Policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#managing-the-links), which described how links to services should be handled:

> The default behaviour is to enable autostarting your package’s daemon.

Here I’m reading “autostarting” in a wide sense; technically since this section of Policy only deals with “links”, *i.e.*, configuring services to start at boot, it could be read as only requiring this, but that would lead to inconsistent system states (*i.e.* a service installed but not started until the next boot). The recommendations in this section and [the next one](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#running-init-scripts):

> It is easiest for packages not to call `update-rc.d` directly, but instead use debhelper programs that add the required `update-rc.d` calls automatically. See `dh_installinit`, `dh_installsystemd`, etc.

> It is easiest for packages not to call `invoke-rc.d` directly, but instead use debhelper programs that add the required `invoke-rc.d` calls automatically. See `dh_installinit`, `dh_installsystemd`, etc.

result in services which, by default, are enabled and started immediately.

Other sections of Policy assume this, or at least result from a requirement to support this; thus in [the section on configuration files](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-files.html#behavior):

> The scripts are not required to configure every possible option for the package, but only those necessary to get the package running on a given system. Ideally the sysadmin should not have to do any configuration other than that done (semi-)automatically by the `postinst` script.

If necessary though, Policy allows the opposite behaviour:

> If, however, the daemon should not be autostarted unless the local administrator has explicitly requested this, instead add to your postinst script:
>
> ```
> update-rc.d package defaults-disabled
> ```

The defaults can also be configured locally; for example `debootstrap`-style chroots are often set up to skip running services.

This section of Policy needs to be updated for systemd, but the general principle still applies.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for it in the sections about services. Somehow missed that *init systems* is exactly what I should be checking…

Comment: One day I would love to find out exactly _why_ this policy came about. It seems quite dangerous to me.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Service will attempt o start on start on system reset. If it was not started before, this will lead to an unattended system state change, which is by far more dangerous than an interactive one.

Comment: @Basilevs not necessarily: if a service is installed but not enabled, it won’t try to start at boot.

Comment: @StephenKitt we are talking about default configuration

Comment: @Basilevs right, and the default is “service starts immediately and when the system boots”. The opposite of that isn’t “service doesn’t start immediately but starts when the system boots”, it’s “service never starts automatically”. But your comment is a good argument in favour of starting the service immediately if it is enabled (so in systemd terms, always using `enable --now`).

Comment: @MichaelHampton, back when that policy was written, people would only install the services they needed. That desktop environments pull in everything in case the user might want it is a more recent development.

Comment: @SimonRichter And suppose I want to configure a service before starting it? This not only happens today, it was also a thing back in the prehistoric times. Today I'll have a firewall going, but for much of the 90s there was no such thing.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, we had firewalls in the 90ies, and if you had a public IP you generally also configured it properly. Also, we shipped rather conservative default configurations (e.g. ISC DHCPd runs, but doesn't answer any requests), and larger deployments usually shipped their configuration files as in-house packages, which were unpacked together with the service.

Comment: @SimonRichter I was referring specifically to Linux, which didn't have any sort of firewall until kernel 1.1.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, Debian never had a kernel older than 2.0.

Comment: @SimonRichter And AFAIK never shipped with the firewall actually blocking anything at first boot, not even today.